# Number of permutation matrices within a distance of a given matrix

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Given a matrix $M$, and a permutation $P_0$, is it possible to easily count, or easily approximately count, the number of permutation matrices $P$ that satisfy $\|P - M\| = \|P_0 - M\|$?

What about the permutations that satisfy $\|P - M\| \leq \|P_0 - M\|$?

What about list all the permutations $P$ that satisfy either the equality or inequality constraint?

If someone knows how to solve this under some useful matrix norm, or with some restriction on $M$, or some other restriction, please do share.

Comment: What  are you using for  $\|\cdot\|$?

Comment: I am not picky. Frobenius norm, for example. Entry wise 1-norm, would also make me happy, or operator 2-norm.